# Rest API - partial update

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm designing a REST API (implemented with ASP.NET Web API, not ASP.NET core, because we can't upgrade it right now).

I'm looking for the best solution to partially update an entity.

For example, the "Person" entity has 100 properties, and a third party system only has to update the "PersonValidityDate".

What is the best and simplest solution to do it ?

I read some article about the PATCH verb, with JSON patch or JSON merge patch, but it seems a bit complicated and not supported by everyone... Is it ?

I'm looking for a very simple solution to do it, that any integrator can understand and use...

What do you suggest ? Is PATCH often used?

If I use POST/PUT and only give the properties to update and ignore the other properties, when the body is deserialized, nullable properties will be null. How can I distinguish the properties set to NULL explicitely and not provided properties ?

Answer (score 0):

> According to **RFC 5789**
>
> Several applications extending the Hypertext
> Transfer Protocol (HTTP)  require a feature to do partial resource
> modification. The existing  HTTP PUT method only allows a complete
> replacement of a document.  This proposal adds a new HTTP method,
> PATCH, to modify an existing  HTTP resource.

So you should use a PATCH request for partial update of the object and PUT for complete object replacement.

And you should not use the complete model in patch request with empty/null fields instead use the new model for PATCH request.

You can check more example [here](https://medium.com/backticks-tildes/restful-api-design-put-vs-patch-4a061aa3ed0b)

Comment: It seems that ASP.NET Web Api doesn't support PATCH... What would be the second best solution for partial update ?

Comment: ASP .NET Web API supports the PATCH request. You have to enable it by specifying into web.config or in startup.cs file

Comment: Are you sure ? Is there a documentation ? I found this article but it requires a lot of  custom code : https://rimdev.io/extending-patch-support-for-asp.net-webapi-part-i/ . Thank you !

Comment: Yes, I am using since the last 3-4 years

Comment: You are using web API or web API 2